Solr equivelant of isnull() or coalesce()
using solr 9.7.0, trying to write a solrj query for:
isnull(field1, field2) in daterange

So far, Chat GPT has me doing:
if(exists(field1) field1:[2022-02-01T00:00:00Z TO 2022-02-01T23:59:59Z]) or if(-field1:* field2:[2022-02-01T00:00:00Z TO 2022-02-01T23:59:59Z])

Is this correct?  Is there a better way two write this solr query?

I should mention that field1, when it "does not exist", in solr admin, nothing is returned on the document for that field.  So in all cases, field1 is in the schema, but in the case that field1 does not "exist" it is not only null, but also a solr admin query will not even list the field.  So it would seem that "exists" and "not exists" should work.  But when I tried "not exists" in the code above, I got a false positive...

I'm not sure what your exact intentions are, but if you want to "use field1 if it exists, otherwise use field2", something like field1:[2022-02-01T00:00:00Z TO 2022-02-01T23:59:59Z] OR (field2:[2022-02-01T00:00:00Z TO 2022-02-01T23:59:59Z] -field1:[* TO *]) might work
